# Are recycled ink cartridges harmful to the printer?

Tags: printer, cartridge

We're looking to replace our print cartridges and came across this page: http://www.cartridgesave.co.uk/ink-cartridges/HP/Officejet-4500.html

The recycled inks not only work out much cheaper per page, I also like the idea of recycling cartridges for environmental reasons

My main concern though, is whether or not I will ruin my printer?

Comment: In my experience, you won't ruin your printer if you use third-party ink (I do). It's hard to answer this question definitively, but in my opinion you should be fine.

Comment: Printer Ink... the most expensive liquid on the planet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a tough one to answer.  There are definite positives about recycled ink cartridges.  They are - in theory - better for the environment.  And they definitely are cheaper then buying new cartridges.

However, there are negatives associated with them too.  Poor quality ink refills can cause print quality issues such as off colors and runny ink.  They have also been known to damage print heads and other printer components.

When it comes to ink jet based printers, the money is made in the ink - not the printer.  So if you buy and use ink refills and they damage your printer, then the cost of a new printer is often less then buying a whole new set of ink cartridges.

So in the end, I think its worth trying if you are looking to save some money and go green.

Comment: Thank you! I may give them a try, I'm not overly happy with my printer right now (even though it is wireless, has a scanner etc) so if it does break, I won't be too down about t

Comment: A personal experience I had with printers was when local stores were selling a printer that was cheaper (by around 15$) than the required set of ink cartridges. Those cartridges did ship with the printer so it would be cheaper to just buy the printers. The companies do make the most money on the consumables.

Comment: @DoktoroReichard As in my experience on working as a PC-shop owner before, catridges that ships with the printer are always have a lower-capacity or it doesn't contain ink at a full level.(Been and always been appx. half of catridge or even less)

Answer (score 4):

If it is a inkjet cartridge (**a cartridge with the print head built in**) then there is no way it can damage the printer. If it is a ink tank cartridge (**the print head is built into the printer not the cartridge**) Then you could get problems with print quality if it is poorly made. If this happens in my experience remove the cartridge put another one in and do lots of cleaning tests this normally corrects poor prints. In extreme cases it can damage the printer but by the time this happens you probably have saved a fortune anyway.

From JP [Http://www.cartridgeexpress.net](http://www.cartridgeexpress.net)

Answer (score 2):

I have used both compatible and remanufactured cartridges for many years and have never had a problem. I've never known anyone to have a problem. I've never even heard of a compatible or remanufactured toner cartridge damaging a printer.

Under United States law, specifically 15 USC 2302(a)(c), using a compatible or remanufactured cartridge does not void your printer warranty.

Comment: I have personally seen poor quality ink damage print heads and print poorly.  Not saying it happens often, but I *have* seen it happen.